# An algorithm to add nodes in a wireless network to obtain connected coverage

Tags: python, algorithm, nodes

I basically have already put Nodes with a specific location and power transmitted from each in a 50m x 50m room and one of the nodes being the Server node that I want every node to connect to in both ways(Directions).
Each node has a circle radius that represents it's coverage around it.
I want to create an algorithm to place extra nodes to the room so that I can obtain a 1 Strongly connected component between all the already existing nodes and the added extra nodes.

I've searched the spanning tree algorithm and new the implementation of them in python but I don't yet know an algorithm or a pseudo code that I can implement to achieve that.
Does anyone know an algorithm or a name of one or anything that can help me implement it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the server different from other nodes in any way? Does it need to be connected differently?

Comment: How do you define "strongly connected"?

Comment: @hyades the server node is just a main node containing the Server which stores all data but it connects just like the other nodes do nothing changes here.
Just I have some already placed nodes in some position but each node has either 2mW or 1.25mW power thats the only thing that differs each node from another

Comment: @Eric Strongly  Connected means the nodes can reach each other both ways.
for example if I have 3 nodes then node 1 can reach the server and the server can reach node 1 and the same for all the nodes 1,2,3.
They all have paths to reach the other nodes.